# How can I add another String and how to retrieve it . I have tried adding another constant in companion object but not working

Tags: android-room

```
class NewWordActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var editWordView: EditText
    private lateinit var editTitleView: EditText


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_word)

        editWordView = findViewById(R.id.edit_word)
        editTitleView = findViewById(R.id.title_word)



        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_save)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val replyIntent = Intent()
            if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(editWordView.text))) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can not save empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                val word = editWordView.text.toString()
                val title = editWordView.text.toString()

                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, word)
               //How can I add title I have tried adding another constant but not working
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SEND, title)
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, replyIntent)

            }
            finish()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY"
        //I addded this but still not working
        const val EXTRA_SEND = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY"
    }
}



I have tried passing data between the two actitvities but while doing that whenever I call the startActivity(intent) nothing is passed
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the data in the other activity? You should edit the question and include that code. The above code looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is as simple as changing :-

```
companion object {
    const val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY"
    //I addded this but still not working
    const val EXTRA_SEND = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY"
}
```

To :-

```
companion object {
    const val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.REPLY"
    //I addded this but still not working
    const val EXTRA_SEND = "com.example.android.wordlistsql.SEND" //<<<<< made value unqiue
}
```

That is the value that both EXTRA_REPLY and EXTRA_SEND to are the same, thus when used as the key in the intent it is just the one single intent extra. They need to be unique values to differentiate the different EXTRA's.